# (Java) How to save many objects at the same time in JList in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jfilechooser

#### Purpose

I am customizing an App for personal use. This App can make many midi files in Java.

I want to save many objects at the same time in JList in Java.
Now I can save the only 1 file at the same time.

**Please tell me why I can’t save many files at the same time in my cord idea below.**

#### Problems

There is no error message.
But I can’t save files if when I changed the code.
I can’t find files in anyplace.

#### My idea

(Premise)

- This App is using JList and JFilechooser.
- I checked and found the save files action from all classes.
- I already changed a detail of JFileChooser. Now I can use multi-plicate select.

(Summary of My Idea)

I use `Files[]`. I changed to be multi-plicate like this.

```
File xxxxx = getSelectedFile()  
File[] yyyyy = getSelectedFiles()
```

#### Source code

(Original code)

```
/**
 * Save Files Action
 */
public Action saveMidiFileAction = getModel().new SelectedSequenceAction(
    "Save",
    "Save selected MIDI sequence to file"
) {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        PlaylistTableModel playlistModel = getModel();
        SequenceTrackListTableModel sequenceModel = playlistModel.getSelectedSequenceModel();
        String fn = sequenceModel.getFilename();
        if( fn != null && ! fn.isEmpty() ) setSelectedFile(new File(fn));
        if( showSaveDialog((Component)event.getSource()) != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) return;
        File f = getSelectedFile();
        if( f.exists() ) {
            fn = f.getName();
            if( ! confirm("Overwrite " + fn + " ?\n" + fn + " is OK?") ) return;
        }
        try ( FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f) ) {
            out.write(sequenceModel.getMIDIdata());
            sequenceModel.setModified(false);
            playlistModel.fireSequenceModified(sequenceModel, false);
        }
        catch( IOException ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            showError( ex.getMessage() );
        }
    }
};
```

(My Idea)

```
/**
 * Save Files Action
 */
public Action saveMidiFileAction = getModel().new SelectedSequenceAction(
    "Save",
    "Save selected MIDI sequence to file"
) {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        PlaylistTableModel playlistModel = getModel();          
        SequenceTrackListTableModel sequenceModel = playlistModel.getSelectedSequenceModel();                   
        String fn = sequenceModel.getFilename();
        if( fn != null && ! fn.isEmpty() ) setSelectedFile(new File(fn));
        if( showSaveDialog((Component)event.getSource()) != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) return;
        File[] f = getSelectedFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        if( f[i].exists() ) {
            fn = f[i].getName();
            if( ! confirm("Overwrite " + fn + " ?\n" + fn + " is OK?") ) return;
}
        try ( FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f[i]) ) {
            out.write(sequenceModel.getMIDIdata());
            sequenceModel.setModified(false);
            playlistModel.fireSequenceModified(sequenceModel, false);
        }
        catch( IOException ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            showError( ex.getMessage() );
        }
        }
    }
};
```

```

If I need add detail information about below items, I will write it.
But I am thinking these are not so important now.

- `PlaylistTableModel.java`
- `SequenceTrackListTableModel.java`
- `.setModified.java`
- `.fireSequenceModified.java`

#### P.S.

I might be not that great with `Java`.

Comment: You should check the length of the retrieved array from `getSelectedFiles()`. Is it really greater than 1? Is the for loop executed multiple times? Try to debug your application, so you know what's really happening under the hood.

Comment: Thanks a comment. I tried to check the length and debug and so on...
getSelectedFiles() is only 1 file i think. If i try to save many times I could some different files.  I also tried to debug. But I couldn't a problems.
Perhaps I need to study about java, swing, Array, JList. Especially, JList is complicated for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quirk of `JFilesChooser`. `getSelectedFiles` will **always** be empty if you have not set the `setMultiSelectionEnabled` flag to true. You need to set that flag before you open the dialog.

You might expect it to return an array containing a single file if multiselection is disabled but this is not the case.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        // This is the flag you need:
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

        for (File f : chooser.getSelectedFiles())
        {
            System.out.println(f.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

If you only want one file, you must use `getSelectedFile` (singular).

---

Interestingly, when multi-select is enabled, `getSelectedFile` will still work and returns the first file which was selected. It seems this class is badly implemented to me.

Comment: Thanks a comment. i tried cording as you said as below.
I researched about JFilesChooser again, and I really understand about multiselection. I also read a Java official homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a comment. i tried cording as you said as below. I researched about JFilesChooser again, and I really understand about multiselection. I also read a Java official homepage.

```
/**
 * Save Files Action
 */
public Action saveMidiFileAction = getModel().new SelectedSequenceAction(
    "Save",
    "Save selected MIDI sequence to file"
) {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        PlaylistTableModel playlistModel = getModel();          
        SequenceTrackListTableModel sequenceModel = playlistModel.getSelectedSequenceModel();                   
        String fn = sequenceModel.getFilename();
        if( fn != null && ! fn.isEmpty() ) setSelectedFile(new File(fn));
        if( showSaveDialog((Component)event.getSource()) != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) return;

 final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        // This is the flag you need:
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

        for (File f : chooser.getSelectedFiles())
        {
            System.out.println(f.getName());
        }
 }
    }
};
```

I wrote like this. When I open this, File menu appeared 2 times. But I failed to save file. there was not files.
I was thinking and trying it 1 day. but i couldn't understand... sorry
I think I need to study java and have basic knowledge... Sorry and thanks you advise.

---

(My expectation)

Using a JList, we couldn't getModel(i)
If I can use (i), I can save many files by "for" sentence easily.

On the other hand, I tried to save and gather MIDI files for Zip file.
Then I need to convert to file type from sequence type (MIDI).

I will try to study there things day by day...
So thanks a comments.